# XSLT Change attribute namespace with Saxon

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, saxon

I try to use XSLT to change tags/attributes namespace.

From input XML :

```
<office:document-meta 
 xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
 xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0">
   <office:meta>
     <meta:user-defined meta:name="Info 1">in</meta:user-defined>
    </office:meta>
 </office:document-meta>
```

I want output XML :

```
<office:document 
  xmlns:office="http://openoffice.org/2000/office"
  xmlns:meta="http://openoffice.org/2000/meta">
   <office:meta>
     <meta:user-defined meta:name="Info 1">in</meta:user-defined>
   </office:meta>
</office:document>
```

My XSLT is correctly changing namespace, except for attribute namespace:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
    xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!--  Match root and output in new namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="office:document-meta/office:meta" >
      <office:document 
         xmlns:office="http://openoffice.org/2000/office"
         xmlns:meta="http://openoffice.org/2000/meta" >
        <office:meta>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </office:meta>
      </office:document>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- 
      Expected <meta:user-defined meta:name="Info 1">in</meta:user-defined>
      Received <meta:user-defined xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" meta:name="Info 1">in</meta:user-defined>
    -->
    <xsl:template match="meta:user-defined">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no" >
          <xsl:attribute name="meta:name"><xsl:value-of select="@*"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this XSL receive :

```
<office:document 
  xmlns:office="http://openoffice.org/2000/office"
  xmlns:meta="http://openoffice.org/2000/meta">
  <office:meta>
    <meta:user-defined 
      xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" 
      meta:name="Info 1">in</meta:user-defined>
  </office:meta>
</office:document>
```

How can I tell Saxon 9.3.0.5 to get rid of the old attribute namespace for attribute meta:name ?

How can I remove xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" ?

If anyone can help thank in advance !

Comment: Your stylesheet does **not** produce the result you claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet  version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:office1="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
xmlns:meta1="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
xmlns:office="http://openoffice.org/2000/office"
xmlns:meta="http://openoffice.org/2000/meta"
exclude-result-prefixes="office1 meta1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="office1:document-meta">
    <office:document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </office:document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="office1:*">
    <xsl:element name="office:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="meta1:*">
    <xsl:element name="meta:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@office1:*">
    <xsl:attribute name="office:{local-name()}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@meta1:*">
    <xsl:attribute name="meta:{local-name()}" select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document xmlns:office="http://openoffice.org/2000/office"
                 xmlns:meta="http://openoffice.org/2000/meta">
   <office:meta>
      <meta:user-defined meta:name="Info 1">in</meta:user-defined>
   </office:meta>
</office:document>
```

which I believe is identical to your expected output.

Comment: Thank you!

I should have thought about renaming prefixes to distinguish namespaces.

Despite the same prefix the namespaces are different.